# I'm using Docusign RestApi 2.1 oAuth and getting 401 without any information on requests

Tags: docusignapi

I've been following the instructions [here](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/authcode/authcode-get-token/) to set up oAuth 2.0 using code grant.  I have the user's token, base_uri, and account_id from the call to /userinfo

When I try to make any calls to the API, though, I'm getting a return status of 401 with no information in the body, so I have no clues as to what's wrong.

The token is still valid, I have triple-checked that.  What else can be done?

I first saw it trying to void an envelope.  Then I tried to get brands as in the link and as in this example.  They both exhibit the same 401 behavior.

```
curl --location --request GET 'https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/<account>/brands' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer <token>'
```

RESOLVED: I discovered what the issue was.  The initial token was not retrieved with the correct scopes (signature%20impersonation).  Once those were granted, the functionality worked.

Comment: maybe the token is correct but the corresponding account is not authorized to see that URL through the API?

Comment: @Guillaume I didn't know the URLs had to be authorized.  What's the call to do that?
We're not using Docusign Admin

Answer (score 1):

As [this article](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/authcode/authcode-get-token/) mentions you need to ensure you request the correct scopes.

**Note:** for Auth Code Grant, you do not need `impersonation`, this is only required for JWT. You do need `signature` scope though in both cases.